# UIScrollview bounce and zoom with fixed top

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Trying to make UIImageView scale when the scrollview is bouncing down.

The idea was stolen from this dribbble: https://dribbble.com/shots/3341878-Product-Page

As you can see, image is like'a scaling when the scrollview is bouncing down.

In my app I have the UIImageView inside the UIScrollview, I can't understand how to fix the top of the UIImageView while the UIScrolvview is bouncing down.

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Check this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481928/imageview-scaling-when-scrolling-down . May be if it helps in your scenario.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apply a scale transform to your imageView based on your scrollview's offsets:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset

        if offset.y < 0.0 {
            var transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, offset.y, 0)
            let scaleFactor = 1 + (-1 * offset.y / (imageViewHeightConstraint.constant / 2))
        transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 1)
            imageView.layer.transform = transform
        } else {
            imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you don't need to "fix" it to top, the imageView will simply scale up as the content offset decreases when bouncing. All you need is that your imageView has a top constraint (plus leading, trailing) and a height.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use one of the following libraries

[MXParallaxHeader](https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader)

[StrechyParallaxScrollView](https://github.com/cemolcay/StrechyParallaxScrollView)

Comment: Using a library for doing something this simple seems kind of excessive.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'cheat' by placing the image above the scrollview and set its height in the didScroll method on you scrollviewdelegate (read content offset and determine image height). If you set the image to aspect fill it will have the effect you want.

Comment: @Simon can you share demo ?