# Parallax UIScrollview over UIImageView background image

Tags: swift, background, uiimageview, parallax

I am trying to develop a home screen where there is a UIImageView behind a Scrollview. I want the scroll view to scroll content over the image and have the image scroll up at a slower pace (parallax).

I've found a ton of solutions using a tableview or scrollview header, but that's not what I want.

I'm trying to mimic a similar behavior in the United Airlines mobile app, but I cannot seem to get the code right.

I have the UIImage View configured behind the scrollview, and I'm trying to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362718/scroll-a-background-in-a-different-speed-on-a-uiscrollview) but I seem to be having trouble converting to Swift 4.

Any ideas?

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfVcX.png)

[Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvJOD.png)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my answer to a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727061/1433612

Assuming your imageView is a subview in the scrollView, use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll` to get the content offset. You can use that content offset to transform the `imageView` with your desired amount of "effect".

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        if offset.y > 0.0 {
            let parallaxFactor: CGFloat = 0.8
            let prallaxedOffset = offset.y * parallaxFactor
            let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, prallaxedOffset, 0)
            imageView.layer.transform = transform
        } else {
            imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }
    }
}
```