# How to increase size of UICollectionView on Scroll

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to increase the size of collectionView on Scroll. It's called Parallax affect.

I have 3 classes with named
1)class `PhotoGalleryViewController`' with storyboard.
`PhotoGalleryViewController` contains `collectionView` and a cell with `imageview`.
2) class `ListingDetailContentViewController`' without storyboard
3) class `ListingDetailViewController`' with storyboard.

`ListingDetailViewController` is appending `ListingDetailContentViewController` as `child`.

```
contentViewController = ListingDetailContentViewController(hideComparable: comparableIsHidden)
        contentViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentViewController.listingDetailViewController = self
        addChild(contentViewController)
        view.addSubview(contentViewController.view)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(contentViewController.view)
```

`ListingDetailContentViewController` is appending `photoGalleryViewController` using Library `AloeStackViewController`. `AloeStackViewController` is `UIScrollView` so thats why i made its delegate in `ListingDetailContentViewController`

```
class ListingDetailContentViewController: AloeStackViewController, PhotoGalleryViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
// MARK: - Private functions

private func setupView(ad: Ad) {
    // Display photos
    if let photos = ad.photos {
        photoGalleryViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Listing", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoGalleryViewController") as? PhotoGalleryViewController
        let photoView = photoGalleryViewController.view!
        stackView.addRow(photoView)
        stackView.setInset(forRow: photoView, inset: .zero)
        photoGalleryViewController.photos = photos
        photoGalleryViewController.ad = ad
        photoGalleryViewController.delegate = self
        actualFrame = photoGalleryViewController.collectionView.frame.height
    }
// Some other stuff
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
// The link i applied here is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481928/imageview-scaling-when-scrolling-down
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if offsetY < 0 {
            photoGalleryViewController.collectionView.frame.size.height +=  actualFrame - offsetY
            photoGalleryViewController.view.frame.size.height +=  actualFrame - offsetY
            self.loadViewIfNeeded()
        } else {
            photoGalleryViewController.collectionView.frame.size.height = actualFrame
            photoGalleryViewController.view.frame.size.height = actualFrame
            self.loadViewIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    }
```

I tried this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481928/imageview-scaling-when-scrolling-down) but not worked for me.
My image is at top of screen. and other things are below.
When ever user scrolls down. Image should be increase.
Kindly help me out to solve this problem.

**Update:**
Answer:
I have done it with help of [library](https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader) called ParallaxHeader. I simply add this library using Pod and follow the tutorial given in library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle I achieved my goal that were asked in Question.
I have done it with help of [library](https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader) called `ParallaxHeader`.
I simply add this `library` using `Pod` and follow the tutorial given in library.